# Adding column in CSV python and enumerating it

Tags: python, csv, enumerate

my CSV looks like

```
John,Bomb,Dawn
3,4,5
3,4,5
3,4,5
```

I want to add ID column in front like so:

```
ID,John,Bomb,Dawn
1,3,4,5
2,3,4,5
3,3,4,5
```

using enumerate function, but I don't know how. Here's my code so far:

```
import csv

with open("testi.csv", 'rb') as input, open('temp.csv', 'wb') as output:
        reader = csv.reader(input, delimiter = ',')
        writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter = ',')

        all = []
        row = next(reader)
        row.append('ID')
        all.append(row)
        count = 0
        for row in reader:
                count += 1
                while count:
                        all.append(row)
                        row.append(enumerate(reader, 1))
                        break
        writer.writerows(all)
```

And the output comes all wrong:

```
John,Bomb,Dawn,ID
3,4,5,<enumerate object at 0x7fb2a5728d70>
3,4,5,<enumerate object at 0x1764370>
3,4,5,<enumerate object at 0x17643c0>
```

So the ID comes in the end, when it should be in the start, and it doesn't even do the 1,2,3. Some weird error comes out.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can suggest the code below to solve your question:

```
import csv

with open("testi.csv", 'rb') as input, open('temp.csv', 'wb') as output:
    reader = csv.reader(input, delimiter = ',')
    writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter = ',')

    all = []
    row = next(reader)
    row.insert(0, 'ID')
    all.append(row)
    for k, row in enumerate(reader):
        all.append([str(k+1)] + row)
    writer.writerows(all)
```

More compact code can be:

```
all = [['ID'] + next(reader)] + [[str(k+1)] + row for k, row in enumerate(reader)]
```

**UPDATE** (some explanation):

Your have wrong `enumerate` function understanding. `enumerate` should be used in `for` loop and when you iterate over `enumerate` function result you get the sequence of the tuples where first item is ordered number of item from list and the second is item itself.

But `enumerate` function return is object ([docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#enumerate)) so when you try to convert it to string it call `__repr__` magic method and cast enumerate object to `<enumerate object at ...>`.

Another words, `enumerate` helps to avoid additional counters in loops such as your `count += 1` variable.

Also you have a very strange code here:

```
while count:
    all.append(row)
    row.append(enumerate(reader, 1))
    break
```

this part of code never can't be performed more than one time.

Answer (score 3):

You should use insert() instead of append(). This will allow you to specify the index where you want to add the element.

Try this

```
import csv

with open("testi.csv", 'rb') as input, open('temp.csv', 'wb') as output:
    reader = csv.reader(input, delimiter = ',')
    writer = csv.writer(output, delimiter = ',')

    all = []
    row = next(reader)
    row.insert(0, 'ID')
    all.append(row)
    count = 0
    for row in reader:
        count += 1
        row.insert(0, count)
        all.append(row)
    writer.writerows(all)
```

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this:

```
import csv

with open('testi.csv') as inp, open('temp.csv', 'w') as out:
    reader = csv.reader(inp)
    writer = csv.writer(out, delimiter=',')
    #No need to use `insert(), `append()` simply use `+` to concatenate two lists.
    writer.writerow(['ID'] + next(reader))
    #Iterate over enumerate object of reader and pass the starting index as 1.
    writer.writerows([i] + row for i, row in enumerate(reader, 1))
```

`enumerate()` returns an enumerate object, that yield the index and item in a tuple one at a time, so you need to iterate over the `enumerate` object instead of writing it to the csv file.

```
>>> lst = ['a', 'b', 'c']
>>> e = enumerate(lst)
>>> e
<enumerate object at 0x1d48f50>
>>> for ind, item in e:
...     print ind, item
...     
0 a
1 b
2 c
```

**Output:**

```
>>> !cat temp.csv
ID,John,Bomb,Dawn
1,3,4,5
2,3,4,5
3,3,4,5
```