# How can I add a column of "ID" to an already created csv but without the actual "ID" header?

Tags: python, csv

Say I have:

```
john,32,male
josh,10,male
sylvia,92,female
```

I need to edit it for some database manipulation later on and have a unique ID for each (preferably in order), such as:

```
0,john,32,male
1,josh,10,male
2,sylvia,92,female
```

I'm seeing solutions online but a lot of them include headers and even trying to edit them, it ends up causing issues.

Comment: Did you forget to post the code that's troubling you?

Comment: have you tried to read your CSV by pandas? Pandas will automatically add an index without a header, and when you export it to CSV with to_csv() it will generate a CSV file with an index without the index header. Is that what you want?

Comment: Maybe this can help:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23261852/adding-column-in-csv-python-and-enumerating-it

Comment: @taipei Surely *pandas* is far too heavyweight for something as trivial as this. It can be written in no more than 5 lines of pure Python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Python Pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

pd.read_csv('file.csv', header = None).to_csv('file2.csv', header = False)
```

**Explanation**

Read CSV file without header into a dataframe

```
df = pd.read_csv('file.csv', header = None)
```

Write Dataframe to CSV file with index but no header

```
df.to_csv('file2.csv', header = False)
```

Piping these two commands together we have the above one-liner

Comment: This is great if you don't mind the overhead of loading the *pandas* module to do something so trivial. One of my favourite things about *pandas* is its consistency - header = None or header = False. Is it any wonder that stack**overflow** is overflowing (see what I did there) with issues around *pandas*

Answer (score 0):

```
with open('file.csv', 'r+') as f:
    data = [f'{i},{x}' for i, x in enumerate(f.readlines())]
    f.seek(0)
    f.writelines(data)
```

Comment: Kindly add other supporting information to your answer. This will help the future readers to understand the answer more properly.

Comment: @AbhyudayVaish There was an answer earlier that gave a very nice explanation on a slightly more complex variation of my answer, if that person would like to edit that into my answer they're welcome to.